# How to create a "fake" row in a SELECT statement of a stored procedure

Tags: sql-server-2005, stored-procedures

I have a stored procedure `proc_Audit_GetAppEmployedRelative`, the purpose of which is to return previous applicants relatives info. The following `SELECT` statement is from the procedure:

```
Select  a.RowID, 
        a.ApplicantRowID,
        a.RelativeName as SearsRelName,
                Case When a.RelativeName <> 'N/A' then 'Yes' End as RelY,
                Case When a.RelativeName = 'N/A' then 'Yes' End as RelN,
        a.Relationship as SearsRelRelation,
                a.RelativeJob as SearsRelJobType,
        a.RelativeLoc as SearsRelJobLoc
    From dbo.App_EmplRelative a(nolock)
    Where a.ApplicantRowID = @ApplicantRowID
```

I have a requirement to return `RelN = Yes` even if other fields are empty in the table `App_EmplRelative`. Basically applicant do not have any employed relative information. I just have to fake a row to get `RelN = Yes` on the form. Please let me know how do I make a fake row, also I still need the above select statement in the proc.

Comment: Can your current query ever return more than 1 row?

Answer (score 1):

You can put the result set into a variable and then test if the result set is empty. If so, you can create a fake row by selecting the actual values. There are better ways, but this is what pops into my brain right now.

```
SELECT TOP 1 null, null, null, 'Yes', null, null, null 
FROM dbo.App_EmplRelative a (nolock)
```

My preference would be to have a test for the @ApplicationRowId first and then query only when valid, or handle the null on the coding side. NOTE: In 2005, you can also code with .NET languages and handle this type of manipulation there.

Comment: If you post code, XML or data samples, **please** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code samples" button ( `{  }` ) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it!

Answer (score 1):

```
Select a.RowID,
       a.ApplicantRowID,
       a.RelativeName as SearsRelName,
       Case
         When a.RelativeName <> 'N/A' then 'Yes'  End as RelY,
       Case
         When a.RelativeName = 'N/A'
            or a.ApplicantRowID is null then 'Yes' End as RelN,
       a.Relationship as SearsRelRelation,
       a.RelativeJob  as SearsRelJobType,
       a.RelativeLoc  as SearsRelJobLoc
From   (SELECT 1 AS C) T
       LEFT JOIN dbo.App_EmplRelative a(nolock)
         ON a.ApplicantRowID = @ApplicantRowID
```

Comment: `CASE COALESCE(a.RelativeName, 'N/A') WHEN 'N/A' THEN 'Yes' END AS RelN`.